# dealing with large CSV files (20G) in ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv

I am working on little problem and would have some advice on how to solve it:
Given a csv file with an unknown number of columns and rows, output a list of columns with values and the number of times each value was repeated. without using any library.

if the file is small this shouldn't be a problem, but when it is a few Gigs, i get NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory. is there a way to create a hash and read from the disk instead of loading the file to Memory? you can do that in perl with tied Hashes

EDIT: will IO#foreach load the file into memory? how about File.open(filename).each?

Comment: This is a work assignment? Show what code you've written.

Comment: Just wondering... did you not accept an answer because none of the solutions helped? Or was there another reason? This question just turned up in my activity again and I wondered.

Answer (score 21):

Read the file one line at a time, discarding each line as you go:

```
open("big.csv") do |csv|
  csv.each_line do |line|
    values = line.split(",")
    # process the values
  end
end
```

Using this method, you should never run out of memory.

Answer (score 6):

Do you read the whole file at once? Reading it on a per-line basis, i.e. using `ruby -pe`, `ruby -ne` or `$stdin.each` should reduce the memory usage by garbage collecting lines which were processed.

```
data = {}
$stdin.each do |line|
  # Process line, store results in the data hash.
end
```

Save it as `script.rb` and pipe the huge CSV file into this script's standard input:

```
ruby script.rb < data.csv
```

If you don't feel like reading from the standard input we'll need a small change.

```
data = {}
File.open("data.csv").each do |line|
  # Process line, store results in the data hash.
end
```

Comment: i am looking for a pure ruby version, but this is very helpful

Comment: @fenec, what makes you consider this version impure?

Comment: hahahah maybe because i don't know how to use it, how would i read the file

Comment: @fenec, by all definitions, this is a pure ruby version.

Comment: Piping in the CSV file might be the part that makes it not pure Ruby. But this method can be applied equally well to a `File.open` initiated data stream

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, in such cases you want to use `CSV.foreach('big_file.csv', headers: true) do |row|`

This will read the file line by line from the IO object with minimal memory footprint (should be below 1MB regardless of file size).